How to display in the console the position with the value of the largest String within an Array
I already know that the largest string within the array has 12 letters, how do I display the value of this String, which in this case is "rioDeJaneiro"?
var cidades = ["Sãopaulo", "Riodejaneiro", "Fortaleza"]

var biggerWord = 0
for (var i = 0; i < cidades.length; i++) {
  console.log(cidades[i].length)

  if (cidades[i].length > biggerWord) {
    biggerWord = cidades[i].length 
  }
}

console.log("--------------------------------------------------")
console.log("A maior palavra tem: " + biggerWord)

I already looked for methods in the documentation but I couldn't find them.


var cidades = ["Sãopaulo", "Riodejaneiro", "Fortaleza"]

var biggerWord = 0
for (var i = 0; i < cidades.length; i++) {
  console.log(cidades[i].length)

  if (cidades[i].length > biggerWord) {
    biggerWord = cidades[i].length
  }


}

console.log("--------------------------------------------------")
console.log("A maior palavra tem: " + biggerWord)




You can use reduce, this way:


var cidades = ["Sãopaulo", "Riodejaneiro", "Fortaleza"];

var longestCity = cidades.reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b);

console.log("The longest city is: " + longestCity);




Save the longest word, or the index of the longest word, instead of its length. When you have the longest word or its array index then you can access the value and any other derived "data" from it, like its length easily.
Examples:


const cidades = ["Sãopaulo", "Riodejaneiro", "Fortaleza"];

let biggestIndex = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < cidades.length; i++) {
  console.log(cidades[i], cidades[i].length);

  if (cidades[i].length > cidades[biggestIndex].length) {
    biggestIndex = i;
  }
}

console.log("--------------------------------------------------");
console.log(`Longest word: ${cidades[biggestIndex]} at index: ${biggestIndex}`);





const cidades = ["Sãopaulo", "Riodejaneiro", "Fortaleza"];

let longestWord = "";

for (let i = 0; i < cidades.length; i++) {
  console.log(cidades[i], cidades[i].length);

  if (cidades[i].length > longestWord.length) {
    longestWord = cidades[i];
  }
}

console.log("--------------------------------------------------");
console.log(`Longest word: ${longestWord}`);




save the string itself is kind of best thing to do

This looks inefficient

@mplungjan Can you be more specific about the efficiency? Can you iterate an array better than O(n) to find the longest string?

The lookup in each iteration cidades[biggestIndex].length (which you changed in version 2) triggered me. Here is mine

Here is a JSPerf https://jsperf.app/jadapa

Way 1:


var cidades = ["Sãopaulo", "Riodejaneiro", "Fortaleza"]

var biggestWord = ""
for (var i = 0; i < cidades.length; i++) {
  console.log(cidades[i].length)

  if (cidades[i].length > biggestWord.length) {
    biggestWord = cidades[i]
  }
}

console.log("--------------------------------------------------")
console.log(`Biggest word is ${biggestWord}, with the length of: ${biggestWord.length}`)



Way 2:


var cidades = ["Sãopaulo", "Riodejaneiro", "Fortaleza"]
var biggestWord = cidades.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  if (current.length > accumulator.length) {
    return current
  }
  return accumulator
}, "")
console.log(`Biggest word is ${biggestWord}, with the length of: ${biggestWord.length}`)




Here is a version that is still O(n) but avoids

looking up the word each time
getting the length of the array for each iteration
Measuring the saved word each iteration

https://jsperf.app/jadapa
All this is of course irrelevant for 3 words.


const cidades = ["Sãopaulo", "Riodejaneiro", "Fortaleza"];

let biggestIndex = 0, biggestWord = "", biggestLength = 0;

for (let i = 0, n = cidades.length; i < n; i++) {
  let word = cidades[i];
  let wordLength = word.length;
  
  if (wordLength > biggestLength) {
    biggestIndex = i;
    biggestWord = word;
    biggestLength = wordLength; 
  }
}

console.log(`Longest word: ${biggestWord} at index: ${biggestIndex}`);




Another alternative is;


var cidades = ["Sãopaulo", "Riodejaneiro", "Fortaleza"];
const arrLength = cidades.map((x) => x.length);

var i=(arrLength.indexOf(Math.max(...arrLength)));

console.log(cidades[i]);



